# Why am I getting socket.gaierror with httplib?

Tags: networking, python

The aim of my program is to send a POST a request to login page, but I'm getting following error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python      
import httplib,urllib       
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost")   
conn.request("GET", "/xampp/mantisbt-1.2.2/login_page.php")  
r1 = conn.getresponse()  
print r1.status, r1.reason   
data1 = r1.read()  
params = urllib.urlencode({'Username': 'administrator', 'Password': 'password'})  
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/html"}  
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost/xampp/mantisbt-1.2.2/login.php")    
conn.request("POST","localhost/xampp/mantisbt-1.2.2/login.php",params, headers)  
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
conn.close()
```

Output:

```
200 OK
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "./client_postnew.py", line 11, in <module>   
    conn.request("POST","localhost/xampp/mantisbt-1.2.2/login.php",params, headers)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 910, in request      
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)      
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 947, in _send_request   
    self.endheaders()    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 904, in endheaders    
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 776, in _send_output     
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 735, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 716, in connect          
    self.timeout)   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection    
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):   
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu. Instead of thanking people who provide answers, please consider accepting their answers. Please do this with this post and all your other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 10 and 11 of your script:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost/xampp/mantisbt-1.2.2/login.php")
conn.request("POST","localhost/xampp/mantisbt-1.2.2/login.php",params, headers)
```

You are creating a **HTTPConnection** object with the wrong arguments: look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html), the signature is:

```
class httplib.HTTPConnection(host[, port[, strict[, timeout[, source_address]]]])
```

**HTTPConnection** takes the hostname, **HTTPConnection.request()** takes the path. Therefore you should write:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("localhost")
conn.request("POST","localhost/xampp/mantisbt-1.2.2/login.php",params, headers)
```

Comment: thank you,but now i'm getting:                                   200 OK
400 Bad Request

Comment: @Kummi_10: that's a different problem which has to do with the POST parameters you are using.

Comment: @Kummi_10: please ask a different question, **if you really need to**. I don't know mantisbt, but I'm sure that if you read the documentation, or if you give a quick look at the `<form>` of the login page, you will be able to answer the question yourself.